# How to fix Error in pip install pandas===1.1.2: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: pandas, numpy, pip, python-3.8

When I tried running **pip install pandas===1.1.2**, it throws this long error:

```
    Collecting pandas===1.1.2
      Using cached pandas-1.1.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
      Installing build dependencies ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [3794 lines of output]
          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
          Collecting setuptools
            Using cached setuptools-65.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
          Collecting wheel
            Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
          Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.16
            Using cached Cython-0.29.32-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
          Collecting numpy==1.17.3
            Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
            Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
            Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
          Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
            Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
            Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
            error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
            × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
            │ exit code: 1
            ╰─> [3080 lines of output]
                Running from numpy source directory.
                blas_opt_info:
                blas_mkl_info:
                customize UnixCCompiler
                  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                  NOT AVAILABLE
...........
            note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I cut the error short because of post limitations. I tried downgrading the python version from 3.10 to 3.8 but the issue still persists. Also, I tried running pip install numpy and it was installed fine. So does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**
another main issue is that the version of python is 3.8 but python3 is 3.10. So I downgraded the python3 version to 3.8 and pip install pandas===1.1.2 worked perfectly [downgrade python3 link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520136)

Comment: Always use `python -m pip <command>` instead of `pip <command>`, because `pip.exe` might be in another directory than your `python.exe`, so you will install it for the wrong Python version. As far as I can tell, pandas 1.1.2 and numpy 1.17.3 should work with Python 3.8 (not with Python 3.10).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to install an older version of pip after then try again?

`pip install pip==21.3.1`

Comment: This is the new error after running this ^
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas===1.1.2